# deprecated scanDouble in iOS 13.0, how would I fix this warning?

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code:

```
let fromStr = (group as NSString).substring(with: from.range)
var scanner = Scanner(string: fromStr)
scanner.scanDouble(&h)
```

However, it seems that `scanDouble` has been deprecated in iOS 13.0. Is there a workaround to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

Please read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/scanner/3200283-scandouble).

Apple has added native methods to get rid of the *Objective-C-ish* pointer syntax:

```swift
let scanner = Scanner(string: fromStr)
let h = scanner.scanDouble()
```

And it's also highly recommended to avoid the `NSString` bridge cast by using native `Range<String.Index>`.